# Cannot access text properties because of hl-line

Tags: faces, help

I want to change somes faces in my system, but each time I want to access `describe-text-properties` I get an answer with `hl-line`, for every text displayed in the buffer.

[image]

Therefore, I cannot investigate and change the settings I want.

For example, I have an issue with `variable-pitch-mode` and the emphasis in orgmode. I would like to be able to understand what is going on.

Comment: Um, turn off `hl-line-mode` with `M-x hl-line-mode`?

Comment: Besides what @FranBurstall said, why do you think you can't access and change the settings that `C-u C-x =` shows you? Those text properties are still present, even if the overlay obscures their effects visually.

Comment: @FranBurstall : Turning it off does not change the *Help* prompt

Comment: @Drew You are right, I can see the faces associated to `org-level-x` and so on.  I will investigate and come back to close the question if needed. Thanks.